# Rendering problem when loading a ListView from a menubar item

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am fairly new to Flutter and am constructing an app that will allow users to select a US state to initiate a search. All was working until I needed to implement a `BottomNavigationBar`. I set up the navigation bar in the initial startup class. When I attempt to load the states ListView by tapping the "Search" menu item, I get rendering errors and the ListView fails to render on screen. My app appears as follows:

[image]

Here is the code showing my `BottomNavigationBar` implementation:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> views = [
    Text('Home'),
    Text('Favorites'),
    StateGaugesView(),
  ];

  void onNavbarItemTapped(int index){
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("App Title") // Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[views[_currentIndex]],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: onNavbarItemTapped,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.star), title: Text('Favorites')
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Search')
          )
        ],
      ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code from the `StateGaugesView` class:

```
class StateGaugesView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _StateGaugesViewState();
}

class _StateGaugesViewState extends State<StateGaugesView> {
  final states = kAllStates;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stateKeys = states.keys;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: stateKeys.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            var state = states[index];
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("${states[index]}", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 17),)
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this app and tap on the Search menu item, i get the following errors:

_StateGaugesViewState

```
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
```

_MyHomePageState

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
```

I've followed an online code sample to set this up and I can't see anywhere where my code is different from theirs, aside from differences in data. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SingleChildScrollView` and then put `Column` inside it, You also can try to replace `Container` and directly pass `Listview.builder` set `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`